# Problem between files with same coordinate reference system

Tags: qgis, r, overlapping-features

I have 2 shape-files. The first created with Qgis and the other with R studio(driver=ESRI). When I import them in qgis i see they doesn't "fit". Both have EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. The only difference I have noticed is that the second file from R studio doesn't have .qpj file. I know that whenever QGIS finds a .qpj file it will be used instead of the .prj (http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html). Is there someone who can help me to find if this file is the problem? What I get with EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 for both files is this:
[image]

Comment: How did you create the file in QGIS? What are the expected coordinates and what do you get when you load them in QGIS, which is correct? I assume you know the correct location since you created the files.

Comment: Can you add the extent of the layers, as reported by Rightclick on the layer, Properties, metadata tab?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I managed to find the problem. At some point to my code in R i had accidentally reversed "x_from x_to , y_from y_to" and the extent was the opposite from Q-file!